# Android add consecutive integers into one textview

Tags: android

I have 10 buttons 1-0 and a text view called 'display'. I have with success coded program to add and subtract to the textView with single digits.. I need to be able to push buttons for inegers to display in text view one after another. Thus if I pres button 1 three times i want text view to say 111 not 3.

my code is such:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            subtotal = 1;
            if (variable1==1) { counter++;} 
            else if (variable1==2) { counter--; }
            display.setText(""+counter);
        }
    });



    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            variable1 = 1;

            display.setText("ADD");
        }

        private void then(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            variable1 = 2;
            display.setText("SUBTRACT");
        }
    });
```

I simply want to pres my 1-0 buttons seperately and populate the textView w/o totalling until I continue the code... =?

Much appreciated!

Comment: just simply append the numbers to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will do:

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        String text = (String)display.getText();
        text = text + "1";
        display.setText(text);
    }
});
```

You can do the similar thing to 2,3,4...

Not sure this is what you want.

EDIT:

If you button has text "1", you can do something like this.

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button btn = (Button)v;
        CharSequence text = display.getText();
        text = text + btn.getText();
        display.setText(text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String num = "";   // Declare num outside of the block
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    num = num + display.getText().toString();// here is the logic which you are looking for..
    display.setText(num);
}
});
```